# How to remove all files from a directory?

Tags: command-line, rm

The closest I've gotten is

```
# rm /path/to/directory/*.*
```

but that doesn't work for files that don't have an extension...

Comment: See answer here, this can remove hidden files as well with out any warning and deleting directory itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832107/delete-contents-but-not-directory-in-linux

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add a real answer, but when using the `shopt -s dotglob && rm /path/to/directory/*` solution in bash, `(shopt -s dotglob && rm /path/to/directory/*)` (with parentheses) will prevent `shopt -s dotglob` from leaking beyond this one command. (Parentheses run the contained commands in a subshell.)

Answer (score 502, accepted):

Linux does not use extensions. It is up to the creator of the file to decide whether the name should have an extension. Linux looks at the first few bytes to figure out what kind of file it is dealing with.

- To remove all **non-hidden files*** in a directory use:

  ```
  rm /path/to/directory/*
  ```

  However, this will show an error for each sub-directory, because in this mode it is only allowed to delete files.
- To remove all non-hidden files and sub-directories (along with all of their contents) in a directory use:

  ```
  rm -r /path/to/directory/*
  ```

* Hidden files and directories are those whose names start with `.` (dot) character, e.g.: `.hidden-file` or `.hidden-directory/`. Note that, in Bash, if the `dotglob` [option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) (which is off by default) is set, `rm` will act on hidden files too, because they will be included when `*` is expanded by the shell to provide the list of filename arguments.

Comment: If you also want to delete hidden files run `shopt -s dotglob` before running `rm (...)`

Comment: Wow that's pretty incredible that you know that off the top of your head.  What exactly does the asterisk mean?

Comment: The * means `all files` ;) `*.*` means all files containing a `.` somewhere in the name

Comment: @Rinzwind, more accurately, the asterisk means "zero or more of any character". So `*a*` means zero or more characters, followed by `a` followed by zero or more characters. It would match the filenames `happy`, `apple`, `a` or `la`.

Comment: This doesn't work for files that start with metadata characters. $ rm *
rm: invalid option -- '8'

Comment: Here's the command you want: rm -- *

Comment: I would've just used `rm -r /path/to/directory` except that will get rid of the directory itself. At least this way you can get rid of the hidden files too

Comment: if directory is empty the command returns error: `rm: cannot remove 'empty_dir/*': No such file or directory`

Comment: In bash, `shopt -s dotglob` is the a way of matching every file in the directory without accidentally matching . or ..: `(shopt -s dotglob; rm -r /path/to/directory/*)`

Comment: does that mean `cd IGNORE /; rm IGNORE -rf *` would effectively remove everything from you computer? (I added IGNORE so no one copy/pastes it into their computer, just assume they weren't there)

Comment: yes. also need sudo ;)

Answer (score 309):

- To remove a folder with all its contents (including all interior folders):

  ```
  rm -rf /path/to/directory
  ```
- To remove all the **contents of the folder** (including all interior folders) but not the folder itself:

  ```
  rm -rf /path/to/directory/*
  ```

  or, if you want to make sure that hidden files/directories are also removed:

  ```
  rm -rf /path/to/directory/{*,.*}
  ```
- To remove all the "files" from inside a folder(***not* removing interior folders**):

  ```
  rm -f /path/to/directory/{*,.*}
  ```

**Warning**: if you have spaces in your path, make sure to always use quotes.

```
rm -rf /path/to the/directory/*
```

is equivalent to 2 separate `rm -rf` calls:

```
rm -rf /path/to
rm -rf the/directory/*
```

To avoid this issue, you can use `'`single-quotes`'`(prevents all expansions, even of shell variables) or `"`double-quotes`"`(allows expansion of shell variables, but prevents other expansions):

```
rm -rf "/path/to the/directory/"*
```

Where:

- `rm` - stands for **remove**
- `-f` - stands for **force** which is helpful when you don't want to be asked/prompted if you want to remove an archive, for example.
- `-r` - stands for **recursive** which means that you want to go recursively down every folder and remove everything.

Comment: I found this to be the more comprehensive and helpful answer, over and above the answer that was marked as Accepted.

Comment: `rm -rf /path/to/directory/*` does not remove a hidden file in the folder e.g. `.htaccess`. Maybe `rm -rf /path/to/directory/.`? Haven't tried it.

Comment: @MarkBerry rm -rf /path/to/directory/.*

Comment: @LilianA.Moraru, I did some testing today. `rm -rf /path/to/directory/.*` only deletes the hidden file(s) in the specified directory. Looking at the @danjjl's comment on @Rinzwind's answer, to also delete hidden files, run `shopt -s dotglob` before running `rm -rf /path/to/directory/*`.

Comment: CAUTION:  `rm -rf /path/to/directory/.*` on my system caused deletion of items in `/path/to`.  Fortunately, I had just backed-up my entire data to a separate disk.  Needless to say, do NOT issue the command `rm -rf /path/to/directory/.*` unless you have backed up your whole computer to a separate / secure location!

Comment: @lawlist My guess is that you had a path splitting issues because of spaces in the path. Example: `/home/user/Important Stuff/directory`. If you do `rm -rf /home/user/Important Stuff/directory`, it's passing 2 separate arguments to `rm -rf`, you are actually calling `rm -rf /home/user/Important` and `rm -rf Stuff/directory`. Make sure to always use quotes around variables and paths with spaces: `rm -rf "/home/user/Important Stuff/directory"` or `rm -rf '/home/user/Important Stuff/directory'`. The issue is not in `rm -rf /path/to/directory/.*`.

Comment: @lawlist The intention was to keep it short and simple because people don't want to read basically an article but I added the warning about word splitting. Note that this is common and not specific to `rm`.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work due to "argument list too long".

Comment: CAUTION: This may cause unexpected behavior, because `.*` also expands to `.` and `..` aka the current and the parent directory. Try `echo .*` in an empty dir. The accepted answer `shopt -s dotglob; echo *` does it correctly, but still fails if the dir is empty, trying to remove a non-existent `*` file. Hint: I used `echo` to demonstrate the glob expansion without doing harm to the filesystem.

Answer (score 62):

To remove all files in directory (including hidden files and subdirectories) run:

```
rm -rf /path/to/directory/{*,.*}
```

Comment: This should be the beautiful accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't this glob match "." and ".." too?

Comment: @hertzsprung - it does, and it will give you a warning that it cannot delete `./` and `../`, but it will still delete the hidden files.

Comment: This does not work on Mac console, hidden files are still there with that command line.

Comment: To remove everything the current directory: `rm -r $(pwd)/{*,.*}`

Comment: I get the error: `refusing to remove ‘.’ or ‘..’ directory`
and exit code 1

Comment: This should **not** be the accepted answer, because it tries to delete the current and the parent directory. See my comment in @Lilian A. Moraru's answer.

Answer (score 21):

To delete all files and directories(including the **hidden** ones) in a directory, you can try the following:

- delete the folder, then recreate it

  ```
  rm -rf dir_name && mkdir dir_name
  ```
- use `find`

  ```
  find dir_name -mindepth 1 -delete
  ```

Here we specify `-mindepth 1` to exclude the directory dir_name itself.
Take a look at the following link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12593/how-to-remove-all-the-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Thanks for your advice and I've added more explanation for the links.

Comment: Be careful, since deleting and re-creating the folder might result in different/wrong permissions for this folder!

Answer (score 13):

If you want to delete only files in /path/to/directory you can do

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -print0| xargs -0 rm
```

or

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec rm '{}' \;
```

You can do loads with `find`, the advantage is you can list what is found without piping it to `rm` so you can see what will be deleted before you start.

Comment: `GNU find` as a `-delete` predicate. If you still want to use `-exec`, substituting `\;` with `+` will gather `rm` calls together, increasing efficiency.

Comment: large amount of files with '+' will cause problems, since list will be too large, same as rm -f *. and when removing large amounts of files from same folder (talking in millons) both of them are not good :) In the end C++ came along and removed files in order of inodes in dir-tree.

Comment: You really ought to add a -- after the rm. Without that if you have a file names -rf or similar will be interpreted as arguments to rm. e.g. xargs -0 rm --  or -exec rm -- {} \;

Comment: you can also provide the -n argument to xargs. That will cause it to split the rm commands to having a maximum number of arguments i.e.  'xargs -n 100 -0 rm --' will remove files in chunks of 100.

Comment: You can also add -maxdepth 1 to ensure that find does not return files from any subdirectories. i.e. find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f

Answer (score 7):

If you also want to remove all subdirectories and the directory itself, you can use `rm -rf /path/to/directory`. But always double-check your line before pressing return, `rm -rf` can cause lots of havock as well, e.g. if you accidentally insert a space after the first slash while having superuser permissions...

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is constantly at the top of Google when I search for this myself:

The other answers suffer from different problems:

1. Some of them include `.` and `..` which is noisy, confusing, and annoying.
2. Some of them forget hidden files (files beginning with a dot).
3. They don't delete in a correct (deepest-first) order to allow directory deletion.
4. They descend into other (mounted) file systems, which is often undesired.
5. They're difficult to extend properly with extra parameters (more on that below).

#### So, to RECURSIVELY delete all files AND folders in a directory, do this:

```
find "${DIR}" -xdev -mindepth 1 -printf "%d\t%y\t%p\0" | sort -z -r -n | cut -z -f3- | xargs -0 -r -- rm -d --
```

Note that I added an `-xdev` argument to prevent descending into mounts (like `/proc` etc.).

### Why not `-depth` or `-delete`?

Despite people constantly downvoting me for this, those methods have a downside: it doesn't seem like they're extensible enough to allow `-prune`ing a subdirectory (without introducing more problems). By contrast with this method, you could insert

```
-not \( -path "${DIR}/subdir" -prune \)
```

before the `-mindepth` argument to exclude `subdir` from having its contents deleted.

Comment: And for depth-first order, there's a `-depth` flag in `find` for that.

Comment: Uh... why not just use [`-delete` with `find`](https://askubuntu.com/a/382987/158442)? `-delete` is depth-first. You're already assuming non-POSIX `find` with the `-printf`, so you might just as well use `-delete` or `-depth -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: @muru: Because I didn't know better... I'll change it.

Comment: @muru: Actually, it seems your method doesn't work with `-not \( -path "$DIR/subdir" \)`... but mine does? Why?

Comment: @Mehrdad what is that supposed to do?

Comment: @muru: Exclude paths under `"$DIR/subdir"` from being traversed entirely. The problem seems to be that `-depth` forces traversal, so the files under that path get deleted regardless.

Comment: @Mehrdad of course, because it's also perfectly valid to read that as "delete everything except that which has a path of `$DIR/subdir`", and that is indeed the behaviour seen.

Comment: @muru: Well clearly that is useless when you want to preserve a subdirectory... whereas mine actually has an advantage here. I don't understand you guys' eagerness to downvote my honest attempt to provide a better solution here; it's extremely frustrating and discouraging.

Comment: Again, of course, because you're using an ambiguous phrasing. `find` is preserving the subdirectory: it's not deleted at all. Be precise in what you want `find` to do, and it will do it.

Comment: @muru: Thanks for repeating yourself. Again, I already responded to you that I want to let the user be able to preserve a subtree and it's not doing that. Again: I have this solution because it's the best I can think of, i.e. I'm too dumb to think of a better one. How about you tell me your more "precise" method that would let the user do such a thing?

Comment: There are probably better ways to express this, but: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7mQ9s8JhJ7/

Answer (score 2):

You can `cd` into the directory and then run the command `rm *.*` just like in DOS if you remember.

Comment: DOS is DEL for files and RMDIR for emptied directories- and hidden and system files must have those ATTRIB attributes removed first. 
Not nearly as simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

To delete current directory, you could for example use `rm -d ./*`

-d tells to delete directories as well.