# How can I change wallpaper automatically?

Tags: desktop-background

I have found a guide for that but doesn't sure if it will work or it is safe to use.
The guide: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-automatically-change-gnome-background-in-intervals-using-bash

I am asking if is these introductions safe and will work? If not, is there any other solutions for that?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Thank you.

Comment: I often wonder whether anyone actually looks at changing wallpaper since, if you are doing any work at all, almost all the wallpaper is obscured and all you're doing is using more computing power as a background activity.

Comment: @cup yes, I don't see my wallpaper too much but when I close tabs, I want to see something different.

Comment: @cup well yes, but the nice thing about computers is that they're really powerful. The computing power used by switching wallpapers is negligible, so why not use it to provide a bit more eye candy? Even if you only see it once in a while

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The script worked when I tested in GNOME SHELL 3.36.6

```
[admin@ADMIN ~]$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.6
[admin@ADMIN ~]$
```

Here is the modified content under my `$HOME/.profile` file.

```
# start my custom script for setting random background wallpapers
if [ -f "$HOME/wp.sh" ] ; then
    bash $HOME/wp.sh &
fi
```

Here is the modified content under my `$HOME/wp.sh` file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to set random background wallpapers on my GNOME desktop
# set base path
export wallpaper_path=/home/admin/Pictures
shopt -s nullglob
# store all the image file names in wallpapers array
wallpapers=(
    "$wallpaper_path"/*.jpg
    "$wallpaper_path"/*.jpeg
    "$wallpaper_path"/*.png
    "$wallpaper_path"/*.bmp
    "$wallpaper_path"/*.svg
)
# get array size
wallpapers_size=${#wallpapers[*]}

# set wallpapers in incremental order
index=0
while [ $index -lt $wallpapers_size ]
do
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "${wallpapers[$index]}"
    # index is maxing out, so reset it
    if [ $(($index+1)) -eq $wallpapers_size ]
    then
        index=0
    else
        index=$(($index + 1))
    fi
    # keep the wallpaper for the specified time
    sleep 1m
done
```

Wallpapers changed at 1m interval as expected.

Comment: thank you, also, can you tell me these codes are safe to use if you understand these codes?

Comment: Nothing risky.. script is safe.. when ever you don't need to run the script.. just comment or delete those lines in `$HOME/.profile` file

Comment: Beautiful script, thank you.

Comment: If you are using dark mode on 22 you should change `picture-uri` to `picture-uri-dark` or the change will not appear. @UnKNOWn no reason not to edit in both to the script if you want, or add an If Statement and first check for `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme` to be `'prefer-dark'`

Answer (score 1):

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background
```

to check current settings

```
org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-opacity 100
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/dragon/.config/variety/wallpaper/wallpaper-clock-cf2949fe1879b8c3ec551eca76b4f396.jpg'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark 'file:///home/dragon/.local/share/backgrounds/2022-12-19-00-32-40-wd-wallhaven-wallhaven-l3zmwy.jpg'
org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000000000'
org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000000000'
org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

you might see two different wallpapers file locations. add extra duplicate line and it will change desktop background in dark mode too

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "${wallpapers[$index]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to define a custom XML-file and feeding that to the wallpaper settings. No need for complicated `crontab` stuff. Just let the **standard** wallpaper application do its magic.

This requires a tool named 'Gnome tweaks' to point to this newly to-be-created XML-file.

(as a sidenote: this is what Shotwell will also do for you, however, it will copy the files to a new location which is, in my opinion, not optimal ... [Shotwell website](https://shotwell-project.org/doc/html/share-background.html))

```bash
$> sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then create a bash-script. The script can be placed in your `~/bin` folder (e.g. `/home/martin/bin/create-slideshow`) so it is available from every location when using a terminal:

```bash
  martin@ubuntu:~> create-slideshow
```

You could also put a call in in your `~/.profile` file so it runs every time you login. (use an editor or run the statement below only once).

```bash
  martin@ubuntu:~> echo '~/bin/create-slideshow' >> ~/.profile
```

```bash
# Change these parameters to change the location of your images and duration

FOLDERNAME=~/Pictures/Wallpapers/Slideshow
CONFIG_FILE=slideshow.xml
DURATION=30
TRANSITION_TIME=2

# Use a HEREDOC to create the first fixed part of the XML
cat << PREAMBLE > $CONFIG_FILE
<background>
  <starttime>
    <year>2000</year>
    <month>01</month>
    <day>01</day>
    <hour>00</hour>
    <minute>00</minute>
    <second>00</second>
  </starttime>
PREAMBLE
  
previousfile=""

for filename in $FOLDERNAME/*.{jpg,png,jpeg} ; do
  fullpath=$filename
  
  if [ -f "$fullpath" ] ; then
      # the next statement might help in some cases!
      # chmod a-w "$fullpath"
      
      if [ "$previousfile" != "" ]; then 
          echo "<transition>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
          echo "  <duration>$TRANSITION_TIME.00</duration>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
          echo "  <from>$previousfile</from>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
          echo "  <to>$fullpath</to>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
          echo "</transition>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
      fi 

      echo "<static>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
      echo "  <duration>$DURATION.00</duration>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
      echo "  <file>$fullpath</file>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
      echo "</static>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
      

      previousfile=$fullpath
  fi
done
echo "</background>" >> $CONFIG_FILE
```

After you have copied the contents of the script above to your `~/bin` folder, make it executable:

```bash
  martin@ubuntu:~> chmod u+x ~/bin/create-slideshow
```

The script's behaviour can be modified using the first four variables.

Then open the Gnome Tweak tool. Go to the section where themes and backgrounds can be set and use the file-picker to choose not an image file, but the XML instead.  (sorry only Dutch GUI here so screendumps are rather useless). See also the instruction [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SlideshowWallpapers) at Help Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4812/wallpaper-switcher/ which gives you a GUI.